# Binning data by row values with minimum sample size

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, binning

I’m trying to figure out how to create bins with a minimum sample size that also accounts for values in a specific column.

So, in the dummy data below, I want to create bins that have a minimum number of 6 samples in them, but if a bin includes a row with a specific value from column a, I want that bin to also include all other rows with that same value. I also do not want any bins to only contain 1 unique value from row a. I then want the output to have a row with a mean of the unique values in column a, a mean of all values in column b and a column with sample size.

```
 df<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10),
           b=c(12,13,11,12,12,11,15,13,12,11,14,15,11,14,12,11,14,12,13,15,11,11,12,13,14,16,14,13,15,13,15))
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
  mean.a   mean.b n
1    2.0 12.33333 9
2    5.0 12.83333 6
3    7.0 12.66667 6
4    8.5 13.28571 7
```

This is what I have so far:

```
x<-df
final<-NULL

for(i in 1:16){
  x1<-x[1:6,]
  x2<-x[-c(1:6),]
  x3<-rbind(x1, x2[x2$a==x1$a[6],])
  n<-nrow(x3)
  y<-mean(x3$b)
  z<-mean(unique(x3$a))
  f<-data.frame(mean.a=z, mean.b=y, n=n)
  final<-rbind(final,f)
  x<-x[-c(1:n),]
}
final<-final[complete.cases(final),]
```

The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to not have a single bin with one unique value in column a. For example, in the third bin, all 6 rows have mean.a$a=7, but I would like to add the next sequential row and all rows with that row value in column a to that bin (which would be all rows that have mean.a$a=8 in this case).

Also, I can't figure out how to get the loop to continue looping through without having 1:number at the top, and then just deleting the rows with NAs afterwards, this isn't a huge deal, but that's the reason it's kind of messy.

I'm not attached to this loop by any means, and if there's a simpler way to answer this question, I'm all for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution for the problem, where `get_6` will return a group variable based on the column `a`. The conditions are met in `get_i` function inside, starting from index `6` and move forward until we find the next index that is not equal to the current value and the length of unique values is not equal to `1`, every time we found a sequence that satisfies the condition we increase the `id` by one and the result will be similar to what you get from the `rleid` function from `data.table`, from there, summary statistics can be calculated based on this group variable:

```
get_6 <- function(vec, id = 1) {
    if(length(vec) < 6) NULL
    else {
        get_i <- function(x, i = 6) {
            if(length(x) == i) i
            else if(x[i + 1] != x[i] && length(unique(x[1:i])) != 1) i
            else get_i(x, i + 1)
        }
        ind <- get_i(vec)
        c(rep(id, ind), get_6(vec[-(1:ind)], id + 1))
    }
}

s <- get_6(df$a)
s
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

library(dplyr)
df[1:length(s), ] %>% 
                      mutate(g = s) %>% group_by(g) %>% 
                      summarize(n = n(), mean.a = mean(unique(a)), mean.b = mean(b))

#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]

#      g     n mean.a   mean.b
#  <dbl> <int>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1     9    2.0 12.33333
#2     2     6    5.0 12.83333
#3     3     9    7.5 12.44444
#4     4     7    9.5 14.28571
```